# HTML and CSS using Jquery Mobile in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: android, html, css, visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile

I am a beginner in front end technologies and I have a simple task assigned to me.this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh771055.aspx) helped me out but i need this to be done in asp.net not in asp.net MVC.
I am confused how to use Jquery Mobile in Visual Studio 2010 and how to make a page from a screenshot given to me for iOS and Android browsers ?
Please see the screenshot in given link  and tell my any good site or useful hint to do this easy task?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUmE.jpg
 here is screen shot too [image]
It is very necessary that the overall div or table goes behind the top red bar so one should see whole area easily in mobile browsers.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for has nothing to do with jQuery (well a little) and there is no way to "automate" this "easy task" you're trying to do. It's not easy man. :(

you've got to get a responsive front end framework, such as bootstrap or zurb foundation

once you get that, you gotta focus on the "small" styles. This one should be real simple. This example using foundation should get you ogoing.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="redBar small-12 columns"></div>
      <div class="item small-12 columns">
          <div class="itmePicture small-2"><img src="picture.jpg" /> </div>
          <div class="itemDesc small-8">       
                we add content here
          </div>
          <div class="itemButton small-2"> 
               <button class="button-large">Button text</button>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have started my work using JQuery Mobile Builder and editing a theme to get my desired results.
http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Smash.aspx
want to see my progress :) and if you can suggest me more?